# how do I quickly remove lines from emacs buffer

Tags: regular-expressions

In an emacs buffer when editing a file called "log/development.log"
how do I quickly remove all lines containing the word "Render"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can go to beginning of buffer with `M-<`, then `M-x flush-lines`, type your word and hit `RET`.

> (flush-lines REGEXP &optional RSTART REND INTERACTIVE)
>
> Delete lines containing matches for REGEXP. When called from Lisp (and
>   usually when called interactively as well, see below), applies to the
>   part of the buffer after point. The line point is in is deleted if and
>   only if it contains a match for regexp starting after point.

`flush-lines` also has an alias ,`delete-matching-lines` which might be easier to remember for you.

---

You also have `keep-lines` (alias `delete-non-matching-lines`), which deletes all of the non-matching lines, keeping only those that match.

Comment: `M-<` (`beginning-of-buffer`) also works. And I think its alias `delete-matching-lines` is easier to remember for me.

Comment: How can I make emacs display all matched lines to be deleted for confirmation? This will make the action much safer.
I know that if I type `C-s M-o` emacs will summarize all matched lines in another buffer for me, but this is a different command with `M-x flush-lines`, and I have to type the regex twice which may introduce typo. This is why I want a confirmation list.