# How show (filter) only text lines with all uppercase chars?

Tags: text

Suppose I has the next text:

```
test
HELLO
help
HOW ARE YOU
buy
```

I need to get (filter) only text lines with all uppercase chars. So result must be like this:

```
HELLO
HOW ARE YOU
```

Comment: Your result contains newline and space which are not uppercase chars.

Comment: ok, with all uppercase, spaces and newline. How I can do this?

Comment: So the question is about filtering text line by line!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I quickly remove lines from emacs buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40596/how-do-i-quickly-remove-lines-from-emacs-buffer)

Comment: @Drew This help https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68641/keep-lines-only-upper-case-not-working/68648#68648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this? *only-uppercase* is used to test which item should be remove(t:leave, nil: remove). Then *seq-filter* to filter the input items.

```
(defun only-uppercase (str)
  "only uppercase"
  (if (numberp
       (let ((case-fold-search nil))
     (string-match-p "[a-z]" str)))
      nil t))

(defun filter-uppercase ()
  "filter uppercase"
  (interactive)
  (print
  (seq-filter
   'only-uppercase
    (split-string
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))
    "\n" t))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two very useful interactive built-in functions `flush-lines` and `keep-lines` that take a regular expression as an argument that modify the current buffer.

Place the cursor before the lines you want to filter and run `M-x keep-lines` with argument `^[A-Z ]+$` to get the result you want.

Comment: This answer is better. Any idea why does `M-x flush-lines` with argument `[^A-Z ]` and `[^A-Z \n]` also flush the lines of uppercase letters and spaces? Am I missing something? My Emacs version is 26.1.