# flush-lines: only upper case not working

Tags: regular-expressions

Here's some text:

```
test
HELLO
999
help
HOW ARE YOU
buy
aaa
H
d
```

I need to remove all lines without uppercase. The result must be

```
HELLO
HOW ARE YOU
H
```

I tried `M-x flush-lines [a-z] RET` but the output was

```
999
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a minor observation with respect to the way you pose the question.  Do the screenshots add any significant information?  I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll solve it using a dual strategy.

First we say that case matters.

`M-: (setq case-fold-search nil) RET`

Then we keep the lines containing upper case.

`M-x keep-lines RET [[:upper:]] RET`