# Filter text of buffer in a grep-like way

Tags: buffers, text-editing, grep

I want to filter the text of an emacs buffer, a bit like you can filter text with `grep`.

Sounds simple, but I tried googling it and I only get results from people who want to search in a buffer or to grep the filesystem.

That is not what I want. I want to *filter* the text of *a buffer*. I want the text not matching the pattern to be gone and I don't want to grep the files in my filesystem.

Is this possible? I'm currently saving the output of the buffer to a file and doing this in a `shell`:

```
more file.txt | grep pattern
```

Comment: Look at `occur` and `loccur`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I quickly remove lines from emacs buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40596/how-do-i-quickly-remove-lines-from-emacs-buffer)

Comment: No. The answers I got fit my problem better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want the text not matching the pattern to be gone

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `keep-lines` will *delete* lines not matching the pattern (i.e. only keep the lines which match).  `flush-lines` does the opposite, deleting lines which *do* match the pattern.
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` will open a separate buffer showing only the matching lines (which you can use like a compilation error buffer to navigate those positions in the original buffer).  This option is the closest to the 'grep' approach.
- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` will show only the portion of each line which specifically matched the pattern (which is what the quoted part of your question sounds most like).
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `loccur` from https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/loccur.html hides/unhides the text within the original buffer (which is therefore a bit like a non-destructive `keep-lines`).

You can read about those built-in commands, and others, in the manual:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Other Repeating Search`

Also see `(emacs)Compilation Mode` regarding the convenient navigation using the `next-error` and `previous-error` commands.

Finally, note that if you do need to use `grep` itself, you are better off doing *that* inside Emacs as well (not least because you can once again jump from the results to the original locations like in a compilation buffer).  There are many Emacs commands which use grep, and you can read about those at:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Grep Searching`

Tangentially, I'll recommend the third-party grep equivalent to Occur Edit mode, which you can find at https://melpa.org/#/wgrep.

Comment: Amazing! Is there also any way to use `sed | sort | uniq` as well? Maybe I'm asking too much, but just in case.

Comment: @dalanicolai's answer has you sorted there.

Comment: You can also use `sort-lines` and `delete-duplicate-lines` (use `C-u C-u` to properly mimic `uniq`'s adjacent line requirement)

Comment: `occur` is the best solution for me, as sometimes I have to go back to the original buffer to look for lines above and below the match. Thank you @phils, you're a savior.

Comment: @NikhilWagh you might then find the numeric prefix argument behaviour of `occur` useful.  This has the same effect as setting `C-h v list-matching-lines-default-context-lines`.  E.g. `M-2 M-s o` to show two context lines above and below each matching line.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the options mentioned in phils answer, you can use `shell-command-on-region` for this. Select the region you'd like to 'filter' first. When prefixed with a universal argument `C-u`, the sent text gets replaced (you can read its docstring for more info).

I don't know your exact usecase, but generally [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) or [helm-swoop](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/helm-swoop/tree/1b3285791f1dc1fde548fe67aec07214d698fd57) provide similar and generally more useful functionality.